# Issue with pixelated Weight Painting

Tags: animation, vertices, weight-painting

Does anyone else ever run into an issue where weight painting turns things a bit pixelated? I've tried smoothing and blurring out the weights. I'm trying to stop the volume loss in the wrist of this character but it's gone a bit weird...

I tried googling around but couldn't find an answer despite trying for hours. I also checked "Similar questions" with no luck. Anyone got an idea of how to fix this problem?

[image: Right wrist looks weird.]

Comment: It's because you haven't subdivided the mesh .Add a sub-division surface to the object and then ty weight painting. You will see that it is much more clear

Comment: The mesh is already very high poly and adding a subdivision surface shouldn't make a difference because there are many vertices around the wrists, but the mesh makes it look like there isn't. This all worked in Maya without flat surfaces, but recreating it in Blender isn't working for some reason... :(

Comment: I've now tried importing the character (rig + skeletal mesh) into Unreal Engine 4 and it looks fine there: https://gyazo.com/7b18136c49987627269a2c0e9ad9950d (weight painting is far from finished, so ignore volume loss). 
It's kinda annoying that the deformation doesn't look the same in Blender but at least I can work around it...